# How to use tabular with minipages in it that can continue to the next page and not take the whole page?

Tags: tables, page-breaking, minipage, two-column

Let's say you want to have two unequal column-like division in your text for a section, and each section separately. Each section look like the following (it does not mean `\section`).

```
\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}l}
    \begin{minipage}{\textheight}
        {\large A\\ B}
    \end{minipage}
    &
    \begin{minipage}{14.2cm}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item C
            \item D
            \item E.
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{minipage}
\end{tabular}
```

Using several of these in one page is fine. But the problem arises when one of them does not finish in the same page it is started, then instead of displaying as much as possible in the same page and moving the rest to the next page, it leaves the rest of the page empty and start the tabular environment in the next page.

Is it possible to force it to not move to the next page and start showing it from where it is typed (for example in the middle of the page) and only moving the amount of it to the next page that can not be displayed here?

Comment: You can use `longtable` for that. Note it does not break within a row, but only between rows.

Comment: you should provide a small test document not just a fragment. It is rather hard to guess the intent of the fragment you posted. Why have a minipage in a `p` column, that is already a `\parbox`? why specify a minipage  that is as _wide_ as `\textheight`? Unless your page is less than 3cm tall, that minipage can not possibly fit in the 3cm p column?